# Почему Вы (или вы) ждёте от отвечающих строго делового стиля изложения?

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

Мне не снизили оценку за ответ, но выделили всю неформальную (обсценной не пользуюсь) лексику ("уау!", "туева хуча", нетушки", "нетути" и подобное) с вежливой просьбой "не раскачивать сайт - ему и так нелегко живётся"...

Я просто убеждена, что просторечия, умеренный олбанский, междометия (как реакция), окказионализмы, диалектизмы, звукоподражания (как та же реация),

ЕСЛИ ВСЁ ЭТО НАПИСАНО БЕЗ ЕДИНОЙ ОШИБКИ И/ИЛИ ОПЕЧАТКИ,

делают сайт живым, дышащим и облегчают коммуникацию, если это, конечно, не суперспецвопрос (употреблён прозрачнейший окказионализм), как, например,

["Ещё о “йоте”: что такое йотовая палатализация?"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/419625/%D0%95%D1%89%D1%91-%D0%BE-%D0%B9%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B9%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F),

мало предполагающий ответ с ой-ёшеньками, угумками (от угу; перевод: конечно, разумеется) и иными вай-вай-ваями.

Что Вы (вы) думаете по поводу сказанного?

СПАСИБО!

Comment: Будьте добры, дайте ссылку на сообщение с просьбой.

Comment: Тогда я в ответе всё исправила - именно потому, что просьба была деликатной и неназойливой. Пожелание "не раскачивать сайт" помню дословно. Могу ли я по этим ключевым словам найти тот свой ответ? Кажется, это было начало октября или конец сентября. Вопроса я не помню.

Comment: а от кого поступил такой совет?

Comment: Да как-то анонимно, если такое возможно. Кажется, был сигнал о поступившем комменте, но его не было. Я просто увидела, кликнув по призыву, свой ответ открытым, и в нём коричневым были подсвечены слова, просимые быть заменёнными... Точный текст просьбы (я не хотела приводить его в этом вопросе): не раскачивайте сайт - его и так качает.

Answer (score 4):

На мой взгляд, «просторечия, умеренный олбанский, междометия (как реакция), окказионализмы, диалектизмы, звукоподражания (как та же реакция)» скорее затрудняют коммуникацию: я не раз убеждался в этом на личном опыте. Иногда бывает тяжело просто прочитать и понять текст, а несогласованность выражаемой мысли с речевым оформлением (рассуждать о той же йотовой палатализации, употребляя просторечия и олбанский, для меня — дико; разве что в шутку...) может быть признаком, увы, не очень хороших вещей.

Разнообразие используемых лексических средств, безусловно, говорит о высокой культуре речи и развитых навыках создания текста, однако est modus in rebus; чрезмерное их употребление приводит к диаметрально противоположным мыслям.

Все вышеизложенное является лишь моим мнением. По правилам на нашем сайте не запрещено использовать нелитературную лексику (однако обсценную — только в научных и исследовательских целях).